# Python 3, vim 8 and the pythoncomplete error

Tags: python, vim

Editing a python file in vim and hitting `Ctrl+x` followed by `Ctrl+o` in insert mode results in

```
Error: Required vim compiled with +python
E117: Unbekannte Funktion: pythoncomplete#Complete
```

I've read a lot of postings and did a lot of fumbling until this:

- I'm using vim 8.0.54
- installed python and vim are both 32 bit
- Vim `:vers` returns ... `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn`
- the `python35.dll` file mentioned in `:vers` `-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python35.dll\"` is located in in the same folder as the `gvim.exe`
- in my `_vimrc` `let g:pymode_python = 'python3'` should tell vim to user python3
- `:echo has ('python3')` returns 1

But the error still remains... any idea besides the error in front of the keyboard?

update 2016-11-08:

It's not a good way, but it solved my problem. I changed
`setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete` to
`setlocal omnifunc=python3complete#Complete` in the `python.vim` file in the `ftplugin-folder`. Now it works just fine. Any recommendations to achieve the same without modifying the python.vim file?

update 2016-11-08:

Finally solved it with `autocmd BufNewFile *.py :set omnifunc=python3complete#Complete` in my _vimrc

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Vim you compiled?  The `vers` results looks correct.  The error `E117` is specific to calling a function using vim's `eval` feature.

However, the `let g:pymode_python = 'python3` variable is for a specific "python-mode" plugin.

1. *Is the `python3` library in your search path?*
2. *Were `python` and `python3` compiled with `--enable-shared`?*

are the questions to answer.

Not sure if vim searches it's own executable folder first or not, but to check so, you can do:

> To use the Python interface the Python DLL must be in your search path.  In a
>   console window type "path" to see what directories are used.

A bit more insight possible in the docs: [doc/if_pyth.html#python-dynamic](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#python-dynamic)

HTH